# Firebase & Swift: Update user information in realtime on app after it updates on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

My app requires you to follow at least four people (or else the buttons say "Follow at least 4 friends") in order to start answering a multiple choice style Q&A about the people you are following. Right now, whenever a user follows someone, it is updated on firebase but the person they follow does not show up in realtime on the MCQ/Q&A page unless I run the app from the beginning.

How can I get it to update in realtime instead of having to re-run from the beginning?

UPDATE:

I have changed my previous observeSingleEvent function to the observe function with DataEventType.value and it is better than before since it updates when I follow and unfollow people but ONLY if the user has more than 4 followers.

Right now, if I unfollow below 4 people it shows "follow at least 4 friends correctly" but as soon as I follow back up to 4 or more the buttons call 4 random users but freeze and cannot be pressed.

Also when I try to add the dismiss function right at the bottom for both observe functions - it bugs out and won't let me go onto the page

Here is the updated code (I hope i explained it correctly and sorry if it seems like a stupid question I appreciate any help/explanation) - thanks in advance :)

The function that is being called in the viewDidLoad is:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
var currNames: [String] = []
var currIds: [String] = []
let imageViewA = UIImageView()
let imageViewB = UIImageView()
let imageViewC = UIImageView()
let imageViewD = UIImageView()

func getFourRandomNodesAndPrintUserName() {
    self.currNames = []
    self.currIds = []

    var myKeyArray = [String]()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = self.ref.child("following").child(uid) //retreives all nodes in the following node
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.children.allObjects)
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            myKeyArray.append(key)
    }

        var randomKeyArray = [String]()
        let numFollowers = min(4, myKeyArray.count)
        for _ in 0..<numFollowers { //will iterate four times
            let count = myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
            let randomUserKey = myKeyArray[randomInt]
            randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
            myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again
        }

        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count
        var namesRemaining = numberOfKeys
        var names = [String]()
        var namesWithUrl = [String : String]()
        var profileImages = [String]()

        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
                print(name)
                print(profileImageUrl)
                namesRemaining -= 1
                names.append(name)
                profileImages.append(profileImageUrl)
                namesWithUrl[name] = profileImageUrl

                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)

                if numFollowers <= 3 {
                    self.optionA.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.isEnabled = false

                    self.optionB.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.isEnabled = false

                    self.optionC.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionC.isEnabled = false

                    self.optionD.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionD.isEnabled = false
                }
                else if namesRemaining == 0 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                    let optionAUrl = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[0]]!)
                    self.imageViewA.sd_setImage(with: optionAUrl)

                    self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal)
                    let optionBUrl = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[1]]!)
                    self.imageViewB.sd_setImage(with: optionBUrl)

                    self.optionC.setTitle(names[2], for: .normal)
                    let optionCUrl = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[2]]!)
                    self.imageViewC.sd_setImage(with: optionCUrl)

                    self.optionD.setTitle(names[3], for: .normal)
                    let optionDUrl = URL.init(string: namesWithUrl[names[3]]!)
                    self.imageViewD.sd_setImage(with: optionDUrl)
                }
                //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //it works when i don't include this otherwise there is a bug

            })
        }
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //it works when i don't include this otherwise there is a bug out
    })
}
```

UPDATE:

I've copied a snippet of my Realtime DB JSON structure from firebase:

```
"following" : {
      "MJxCFUX0jpXJD1a2u0iqt6xSAdB3" : {
      "5W6Qf4cJKQb5nY1PthMUelHLShy2" : true,
      "GU03rUQPrIX4zleX1S8L8anSWmn2" : true,
      "MfeIehKJKzS2Cf0kA0JTmHZGWSu1" : true
    },
      "MfeIehKJKzS2Cf0kA0JTmHZGWSu1" : {
      "5W6Qf4cJKQb5nY1PthMUelHLShy2" : true,
      "GU03rUQPrIX4zleX1S8L8anSWmn2" : true,
      "MJxCFUX0jpXJD1a2u0iqt6xSAdB3" : true,
      "nZLf70wvZUYqrAExXmnSX9G7Rar2" : true
    },
      "nZLf70wvZUYqrAExXmnSX9G7Rar2" : {
      "5W6Qf4cJKQb5nY1PthMUelHLShy2" : true,
      "FwUzqbn49FP5jS5mIuaAEnrxvpj2" : true,
      "GU03rUQPrIX4zleX1S8L8anSWmn2" : true,
      "MJxCFUX0jpXJD1a2u0iqt6xSAdB3" : true,
      "MfeIehKJKzS2Cf0kA0JTmHZGWSu1" : true
    }


"users" : {
     "5W6Qf4cJKQb5nY1PthMUelHLShy2" : {
      "email" : "aaaa@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "Aaaa",
      "fullname_lowercase" : "aaaa",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pinion-4896b.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2F5W6Qf4cJKQb5nY1PthMUelHLShy2?alt=media&token=eba41189-98dc-45d0-bccc-769cc8fa872f"
    },
     "FwUzqbn49FP5jS5mIuaAEnrxvpj2" : {
      "email" : "ffff@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "Ffff",
      "fullname_lowercase" : "ffff",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pinion-4896b.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2FFwUzqbn49FP5jS5mIuaAEnrxvpj2?alt=media&token=55649e15-4e6c-4b44-b804-1b4a9e8e4272"
    },
}
```

Comment: I know they are updates but that's way too much code to ask us to go through. Please edit the question and reduce the code the minimum required to reproduce the issue. See and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, links break and that would invalidate the question so include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Sure - sorry i'm new to this so I was just trying to make it clear by giving as much info but I understand, i'll cut it down :)

Comment: That's better but the issue is still unclear. Reading through the explanation it sounds like you are able to load that data you want successfully from Firebase but you're having a freezing issue at some point? That would indicate a logic issue - perhaps a var being set to nil, or a loop not iterating the correct number of times. I would suggest putting some breakpoints in your code and walking through it and analyze your vars ensuring they have expected values or until the freeze occurs - this will help narrow down which part of the code is not working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried going through it and I think the error might be coming from: "if numFollowers <= 3 {....}, else if namesRemaining == 0 {...}" since it freezes when i follow less than 4 people then follow over 4 - do you know if there is a better way to re-write this?

Comment: That's an odd if statement. If numFollowers <= 3 then those statements will executed. If numFollowers > 3 then that falls through and tests if namesRemaining == 0. What if numFollowers = 4 and namesRemaining = 1? No statements will execute - is that the intention? More importantly, `numFollowers <= 3 ` isn't going to ever work as you're not changing the value of `numFollowers` i.e. the followers node is read by .value and suppose there are 4 child nodes. `let numFollowers = min(4, myKeyArray.count)` will set numFollowers to 4 and it does't appear to change after that.

Comment: Oh ok I think i understand - essentially, what I am trying to do is access the following node and enter the child node of the current user and if it has 3 or less people then make the button read "Follow at least 4 friends" but if there are 4 or more objects (the user is following 4+ people) then it grabs 4 random users and places them on each button

Answer (score 0):

So you can use `observ` function instead of `observeSingleEvent`.
Example from google doc:
`postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})`

DataEventType (it's enum) have next values:
`/// A new child node is added to a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded,
    /// A child node is removed from a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved,
    /// A child node at a location changes.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged,
    /// A child node moves relative to the other child nodes at a location.
    FIRDataEventTypeChildMoved,
    /// Any data changes at a location or, recursively, at any child node.
    FIRDataEventTypeValue`

`Observ` function  works like listener-observer pattern, so don't forget to dismiss subscription on observing event.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped but there are still a few things that aren't working correctly - I have added an update to the original code and would really appreciate your help

Comment: First of all, you should use observeSingleEvent for single user data fetching.
Also, please, share your realtimeDB data structure.

Comment: Can you share realtimeDB structure in Json-like presentation?

Comment: Sure i have added a screenshot of my firebase realtimeDB